# Django - Is it possible to show loader until a start page is loaded?

Tags: django

My view function takes a long time until returning a template. So, I'd like to show something to a user while running the function.
Is it possible to show loader until a start page is loaded?
What's important is the loader should be shown when loading the first page after first visit of a user?

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to fetch the page using JS. You could use something like [Intercooler](http://intercoolerjs.org) or [PJAX](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) which provides HTML attributes that show a spinning animation while loading the content via AJAX.

A better solution would be to make your page faster. There are several things you should consider:

1. Check that all Model fields that you are using for filtering or sorting have set `db_index=True` unless the tables are small (few hundred entries) or the fields are already unique or foreign/primary keys. Also check that your DB does sorting and merging in RAM not on disk (== the DB has enough RAM resources and has also the correct configuration to use it).
2. Sometimes, if you show a list of model instances you end up making separate DB requests per row if you access related models in your template. Again, check which statements your DB executes and have a look at Django's `select_related`, `prefetch_related`, `values` and `values_list` methods that can dramatically increase lookup performance. Make sure your template context contains all necessary data and only the necessary data (e.g. pageing, how much, or maybe you should consider a search index like SOLR or Elastic which can be integrated nicely via Django Haystack).
3. Load everything except heavy data at once in your main view, which also includes JS. The JS then uses AJAX to load the rest from a second Django view which returns an HTML snippet that your JS simply adds to the DOM.

It really depends on how comfortable you are with JS and how much you want to stick to HTML to make as much use of Django as possible (thinking of Django Forms for example). But first, [tune your DB setup](http://blog.it-agenten.com/2015/04/tuning-django-orm-text-queries/) (disclaimer: I have written that article).

Answer (score 0):

it's better to make a request with javascript to your Django endpoint, until you get a response back from your server you should show your loader, and when you get the response back successfully you should make `display: none` for loader and mak `display: block` for your loaded content

1. Create a function in **views.py** and send [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects). URL example: **http://localhost:8000/somedata**
2. Render any other HTMLlet's say it's **index.html**. URL example: **http://localhost:8000/home**
3. That **index.html** file need to have some JavaScript, let's say **main.js**
4. In main.js make a request to **http://localhost:8000/somedata** and fetch data. Use async javascript that way you can easily track fetched data or not